# .php file on website, source in html

Tags: php, html

I am looking at a site for which I have the php source. The pages are all php pages: index.php, home.php, about.php. These files all contain pure php code.

However, I've opened up this website, say about.php, and viewed the page's source. I see HTML code which is laying out the page. Why isn't this page source in php?

Comment: PHP is a server side language. In plain terms, this means that the server uses a PHP script to generate the data that will be sent to the client, rather than sending the PHP script itself. Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php for more info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be a horrendous security hole if you could view source and see the underlying PHP code - you'd see database credentials, trade secrets, etc.

PHP is a server-side language. It gets executed on the server, usually to build HTML that then gets output to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

The php code is processed by the server to produce the html code sent to the browser that requested it.

Answer (score 1):

because PHP is a server side language, you can't see the source code ... you are client, you only see the HTML tags, HTML is a client side language ...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, html is used to format the page and it's information. This information is generated dynamically via PHP and then sent off to the client requesting the information.

As other users have pointed out, you do not want your webserver's source code to be publicly available; as it is a huge security risk.

There are many reasons that html exists, but I think that ventures outside of the bounds of your question.